# Delete data from a specific partition in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I would like to delete data from a specific partition using the partition ID. I got queries to truncate data from specific partition for SQL Server 2016 but did not find any query for lower versions.

I tried below query to delete only data from partitions with partition id 14 and 15.

```
DELETE FROM partitiontable1 WITH (PARTITIONS (14 to 15))
```

Will the delete statement remove the partition itself along with data?

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was within truncate, but that's 2016 onwards, if its to remove all the data in the partition create a switching table on the correct filegroup and switch the partition out and truncate that switched table.